# Paperclip Unpermitted parameter: image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, paperclip, react-on-rails

I am trying to get Paperclip to upload an image to s3 from my festival model on form submit but am receiving the **Unpermitted parameter: image.** error

I have checked the strong params, the model content validation and read through the paperclip documents with no avail.

I think I have narrowed the problem down to my post request to the DB cannot handle the File object that gets assigned to festival.image, but can't figure out how I would represent this in the post request.

I am capturing the data in rails using react on rails on the front end with Rails as the backend. I was following along with this sample code https://github.com/carlbaron/react-file-upload-demo

I also use React-dropzone to capture the uploaded file and it adds the preview attribute for the image preview.

Been stuck on this for some time now, any help greatly appreciated!

**Beginning of the post request printed to console**

```
Processing by FestivalsController#create as JSON

Parameters: {"festival"=>{"fest_name"=>"Test Festival", "image"=>{"preview"=>"blob:http://localhost:5000/76b95cb5-45bf-46a9-ba7b-f5b9ad127521"}}}

 | Unpermitted parameter: image
```

**Festival object printed to the console**
[image: festival object]
**Post Request to the DB via axios**

```
 postFestival(festival) {
     let config = {
       responseType: 'json',
       processData: false,
       contentType: false,
       headers: ReactOnRails.authenticityHeaders(),
    };
      let str = JSON.stringify(festival);
      console.log("ENTITY IS  " + str);

      //returns
      //ENTITY IS  {"fest_name":"Test Festival","image":{"preview":"blob:http://localhost:5000/76b95cb5-45bf-46a9-ba7b-f5b9ad127521"}}

      return(
        request.post('/festivals/create', {festival}, config)
      );
     },
```

**Festival.rb**

```
 class Festival < ApplicationRecord

     has_attached_file :image, default_url: "/assets/ASOT-COVER.png"
     validates_attachment :image,
                      content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] }


    end
```

**Festivals Controller**

```
 def create

     @festival = Festival.create(festival_params)

     puts "festival.image =" + @festival.image.inspect
     #returns = festival.image =#<Paperclip::Attachment:0x007fc288868bf0 @name=:image, @name_string="image", @instance=#

     if @festival.save
        puts "Festival SAved = + " + @festival.inspect
        #returns the festival object saved to the DB minus the image param
     else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: @festival.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
        puts "ERROR = " + @festival.errors.inspect
      end
    end

  private

    def festival_params

       params.require(:festival).permit(:fest_name, :fest_organizer, :fest_location,
                                      :fest_date, :fest_url, :fest_venue, :fest_description,
                                     :image)
    end
   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `image` parameter in your request is a hash `"image"=>{"preview"=>"blob:http://localhost:5000/76b95cb5-45bf-46a9-ba7b-f5b9ad127521"}`, you will need to modify your `festival_params` method like this:

```
def festival_params
   params.require(:festival).permit(:fest_name, :fest_organizer, :fest_location,
                                  :fest_date, :fest_url, :fest_venue, :fest_description,
                                 { image: :preview })
end
```

Let me know if it solves the error.

Comment: Thank you, that got rid of the unpermitted param error! Now I get the Paperclip No Handler Error for {"preview"=>"blob:http://localhost:5000/76b95cb5-45bf-46a9-ba7b-f5b9ad127521"} but from other stack overflow questions would be Im not passing a correct class to Paperclip so I will try to look into this when I get home!